# Timepicker autoselection of time

Tags: php, timepicker

I'm using UI timepicker. I have a loop for with start time and end time. I would like when the user enter the end time, it copy also in the next start time.

For example:

```
start1: 1:00 -- end1: 13:00 
start2: 13:00 (automatically input) -- end2:..
```

For now my code is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.timepicker.js?v=0.3.2"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker_dynamic').timepicker({
            showLeadingZero: false,
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker_dynamic').endtime({
            showLeadingZero: false,
        });
    }); 
</script>

<?php   for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {   ?>   
<input type='text' name='timepicker[<?php echo $i ?>]' class='datepicker_dynamic' id='timepicker.[<?php echo $i ?>]'/>
  -- 
<input type='text' name='endtime[<?php echo $i ?>]' class='datepicker_dynamic' id='endtime.[<?php echo $i ?>]' /><br>                   
<?php } ?>
```

I try to put  a value in the input but it didn't get the time.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle

Comment: here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Zzwh/6/